# Reload data in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 on a `select` that I'm filling with data dynamically (using json and other filters) all with a function called `list()`.

I would like to call `list()` each time the dropdown is opened to refresh the data.
The only way I could make this happen was calling `.select2("destroy").select2()`

My problem is that it's working only when I'm initiating it from another element. Let's say `$(".header").click(function() { ... })`
It's not working when I call any of the built-in events (`select2-opening`, `select2-open`, `select2-focus`...).

Any ideas how I can call it upon opening the dropdown select?

**EDIT:**
I was able to solve this by simply calling `list()` on event "select2-opening".

It starts with `.empty()` and then starts filling up the `<select>` on which I apply the select2 plugin.

**EDIT2:** 
A better solution was calling the event "select-focus", which reacts better in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

consider using **ajax**  constructor property if you want to reload data from server.
Either you can use **query** callback to build rather remote data reload or local data reload.
Just implement a method that gets updated data

Comment: Of course I considered this. However, this `list()` function is too complicated and requires too much effort to convert its functionality to select2.

Comment: Plus, I just checked it again and ajax functionality in select2 is available only through search, and I need all the retreived options to show up.